# Why chrome.bookmarks.search not searching folder

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm try search folder bookmarks with "chrome.bookmarks.search" but not found enything.

```
  chrome.bookmarks.search('My folder', function(children) {
  children.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child)
    $('#grid').append(child.title);
});
```

Why this code search only bookmarks and not folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a know bug\feature request for searching with folder name, [check details](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/h1M2Ns7JbS0) and [some discussions](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/3ZfozokD2q4)

## Work Around.

Retrieve entire Book Marks Tree using [chrome.bookmarks.getTree](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#method-getTree) and filter folders with missing URL property.